# How do you install Google App engine on Ubuntu 12.10?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, ubuntu, installation

A step by step from the beginning would be much appreciated!

Comment: See http://askubuntu.com/questions/123553/how-to-install-google-appengine

Answer (score 8):

1. [Download the SDK](https://developers.google.com/appengine/downloads#Google_App_Engine_SDK_for_Python).
2. Unzip the SDK in, say, `~/google_appengine`.
3. There are a few programs in the `google_appengine` directory.  You
   can either [add the `google_appengine` directory to your `PATH`](https://askubuntu.com/q/60218/8005) or
   symlink the programs to some directory that is already in your
   `PATH`. For example,

   ```
   ln -s ~/google_appengine/dev_appserver.py ~/bin
   ln -s ~/google_appengine/appcfg.py ~/bin
   ```

   Note that if you add the `google_appengine` directory to your `PATH` by editing /etc/environment (which requires superuser privileges) then **all user** on the machine will have **your** google_appengine directory added to their `PATH`. This could be a security risk for them, and an annoyance if they too wanted to install google appengine.
4. Follow the [Hello World tutorial](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstartedpython27/helloworld) to get started.

Answer (score 0):

1. Download and extract the [zip file](http://googleappengine.googlecode.com/files/google_appengine_1.7.3.zip).
2. Add path to the extracted `google_appengine` folder in the `/etc/environment` file.
3. Log out and login again, now run the command `dev_appserver.py` in terminal, it should not return something like `dev_appserver.py: command not found`.
   `

Comment: Can you tell me how to do so, step by step from unzip onwards PLEASE!

Comment: Lets's say if you've extracted the zip in your home folder then simply append this line at the end of the `/etc/environment` file `:/home/devesh/google_appengine`.
`

Comment: For the record though...if it does return "command not found" which it was doing on my machine it's most likely because the python interpreter isn't associated with .py execution for some reason. When I was having issues with "command not found" I tried python appcfg.py and that seemed to do the trick